# Wrapped function with global variable on window object

Tags: javascript

I couldn't find a concrete question for the following code, but can you tell me why do we call the following and how/when does it get executed

```
    (function (myApp) {
            var helperFunction = function() {
                //helper function body
         };
         myApp.Helper = helperFunction; 
     }(window.MyApp));
```

In above code 
1) What is the difference between myApp, and  window.MyApp?
2) Why have we passed myApp, is it actually getting passed from anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you tell me why do we call the following and how/when does it get
>   executed?

The outer structure in your code is called an Immediately Invoked Function Express (IIFE).  It's really just a function definition that is both defined and called all at once without giving it a name.  It is executed immediately.

```
(function(someArg) {
   // body of function
}(something));
```

It's basically like this:

```
function myFunc(someArg) {
   // body of function
}

myFunc(something);
```

Your IIFE works identically to this above code with the one difference that the IIFE does not assign a name to the function so no name is used within that scope.

In your IIFE, you are passing `window.MyApp` to your function which is presumably an object.  In the definition of that function, the variable that is passed to the function is given the name `myApp`.  So, anywhere inside that function where you refer to `myApp`, it is essentially an alias for `window.MyApp` as they both point to the same object and any change in one is a change to the same object.

Your code is essentially like this:

```
function myFunc(myApp) {
    var helperFunction = function() {
            //helper function body
    };
    myApp.Helper = helperFunction; 
 }

 myFunc(window.MyApp);
```

> What is the difference between myApp, and window.MyApp?

There is no difference.  They both point to the same object.

> Why have we passed myApp, is it actually getting passed from anywhere?

It's a style or design choice to pass it in.  It doesn't have to be passed in.  It could be referenced as `window.MyApp` everywhere in the function if one wanted, but this way, there is a shortcut to use it inside the function as `myApp`.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a self-invoking function. I'm not sure about the exact syntax though :)

To answer your questions:

> What is the difference between myApp, and window.MyApp?

myApp is the function argument. window.myApp is what's passed into the funciton.

> Why have we passed myApp, is it actually getting passed from anywhere?

See the above answer - hopefully it will clarify what's going on.

Basically, the code is equivalent to saying:

```
function myFunction(myApp) {
    var helperFunction = function() {};
    myApp.Helper = helperFunction;
}
myFunction(window.MyApp);
```

Except that it is more concise and doesn't actually declare the function `myFunction`.